# How to create audit trail for a table using Triggers. I am using sybase 15.2 ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, audit-trail

Iwant to post all changes of records of table copied into a separate table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable(
    field1 numeric(13,2) NOT NULL,
    field2 char(4)       NOT NULL,
    field3 char(4)       NOT NULL,
    field4 varchar(30)   NOT NULL,
    field5         datetime      NULL,
    field6 datetime      NULL)
```

This is my table.

I want to create a separate table, which will record, all changes, as and when changes to the above table..

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable_audit(
            field1 numeric(13,2) NOT NULL,
            field2 char(4)       NOT NULL,
            field3 char(4)       NOT NULL,
            field4 varchar(30)   NOT NULL,
            field5         datetime      NULL,
            field6 datetime      NULL,
    idactivity numaric),
    iddatestamp datetime)
```

I want to capture changes of first table into 2nd table (who did insert/update/delete on this table with time stamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Insert, Update, Delete and Instead of Triggers.  You will want to create an Insert, Update and Delete triggers for your purpose.

Here's a short example:

```
create trigger mytable_del on mytable
for delete

as

declare @stuff

insert something into mytable_audit
where something and something else

end
go
```

[Here's the documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X79145.htm). If you have problems with specific parts of your triggers, then you can post those specific code questions here, but it's unlikely that someone here will write your triggers for you.